# Read Config File Line By Line in Kernel

Tags: c, kernel

I am trying to read a config file ( which is located/generated in a specific place in kernel) for a module that I am working.

I can read the file as a whole by using filp_open with O_RDONLY flag (read only ) but I can't think out a way to read it line by line.

Current Code

```
f = filp_open("/etc/my_module",O_RDONLY, 0);

if ( f==NULL) {
    printk("Error in loading config for birdge.\n");
    return 1;
} else {
    fs = get_fs();
    set_fs(get_ds());

    /* read line config here */
    f->f_op->read(f, buf, 128, &f->f_pos);

    set_fs(fs);
    printk("buf:%s\n",buf);
}
```

Linux Kernel Version: 3.8.0-29-generic

What I am trying to achieve is putting each(nth) line into a buffer array(char *buf[128][128]) and later I will chunk out the param and value using pure c.

By that way the variables from the config file could be used in module's runtime and of course I will make some condition checks whether the configs are ok or not.

Thanks

Comment: No, and that's pretty much entirely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: You should read how to ask. This is a terrible question.

Comment: For inspiration for configuring complex things look into how the kernel configures networking, routing and firewall.

Comment: You don't say which kernel it is, I suppose @ZanLynx is assuming it's linux's kernel. You don't explain why it is failing and why you can't use `fgetc()` or any standard function.

Comment: Yeah this is my dummy question. Actually fgetc() is not failing iharob.  I just simply can't use it in kernel space since it is from c's stdlib. What I am asking is the equivalent of that function in kernel.

Yes this is Linux kernel and to be more specific 3.18.xx. I am checking how linux configure networking based on the advice of Zan. Thanks mate for your positive comment.

Comment: @TinAungLin Please remove the `comment blockquote` from the question body, as they're already here in the comments section. Also update the question body with the kernel version you stated in the comment above. If you have anything else to add to the question, for instance, the current approach you're on, add it too as clearly as possible.

Comment: @threadp does this help you mate ?

Comment: you should read the man page for `printk()` which will tell you that the first parameter is the 'severity' of the message, followed by the format string, followed by any needed variables

Comment: Also wanted to point out that even module loading in the kernel is done by user-space loading the module file and then passing it into the kernel, not by the kernel reading it for itself. Also, consider how many horrible things could happen. The file could be on a network or FUSE FS and hang. Even a regular disk might go away on a long vacation with a block error recovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TL;DR: Avoid doing such a thing as reading file-system files directly from kernel space.]

You've it almost done.

The only thing you currently need is to allocate an array of strings using `kcalloc()` (similar to libc `calloc()`, with an extra argument that you can set [for the sake of the example] as GFP_KERNEL), and then loop over the file with `f->f_op->read(f, &chr, 1, &f->f_pos);` (read char by char, similar to libc `read(f, &chr, 1)`... you can optimize this later by reading the file in chunks and process the chunks to avoid tons of reads in kernel space).

This will give you a similar approach to `fgetc()` under kernel land, as well as a similar interface to `calloc()` for your `char *buf[]` array.

You can also implement your own (poorly optimized) `kfgetc()` such as:

```
int kfgetc(struct file *f) {
   char chr = 0;

   f->f_op->read(f, &chr, 1, &f->f_pos);

   return chr;
}
```

And with this example, you can easily create a `kfgets()` (just loop with `kfgetc()` until you find a '\n' or there's nothing else to read).

Note that what you're doing, in general, doesn't seem to be a good practice (to be honest, it is a really bad idea), but putting that aside (as I don't know why you're doing it), the above is a good start to get it working. When it gets to work, then look where you can optimize it (also see how other kernel components retrieve configurations, as stated by @ZanLynx).

Some other useful memory allocators for your case (since `kcalloc()` may not solve your problem if you don't know how many lines will be on the file): `kmalloc()` and `krealloc()` (similar to libc `malloc()` and `realloc()`).

Answer (score 5):

Parsing configuration files in the kernel is messy and dangerous. Don't do that.

If your kernel module needs configuration, this is typically done by passing arguments when the module is loaded, e.g. `insmod example.ko foo=123`. You can declare these arguments in your module using the `module_param` macro. Information on how to do this is available in [the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x323.html).

If your module needs more complex configuration than is feasible using module arguments, it may be appropriate for your module to create endpoints in sysfs for this configuration. Note that this will all mean that your module will most likely need a userspace helper script to configure it. **This is normal and OK.** Writing this script in userspace will be much simpler and safer than it would be to have it running in the kernel.